# Retrofit2 error : Java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL query string "a={action}&type=json&key=15670403" must not have replace block

Tags: java, android, json, web-services, retrofit2

For dynamic query parameters I'm using `@Query` for method `RadioApiClient.getFeeds`

Below is the URL I am trying to manipulate.

`//api.broadcastify.com/audio/?a=feeds&type=json&key=1234567890`

```
public interface RadioApiClient {

    String BASE_URL = "http://api.broadcastify.com";

     @GET("/audio/?a={action}&type=json&key=1234567890")
     Call<List<Feeds>> getFeeds(@Query("a") String action);

}
```

I looked at the documentation but it doesn't seem to be working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```
 @GET("/audio/type=json&key= 1234567890")

    Call<List<Feeds>> getFeeds(@Query("a") String action);
```